# Making Click function of image map appear in specific Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an image map called map and I want the text to show up within my div #show_message. The image map is on the left and the text will appear on the right side. I believe the only problem that I'm facing right now is integrating the show_message div into the script below. Also how do I hide the text before it appears on click? I thought the .()hide would do it but it doesn't work. Please help!

This is my div

```
<style>
    #show_message {
        float: right;
        width: 500px;
        height: 750px;
        position: relative;
        padding:20px; 
        margin:20px; 
        background:#fff;
        color:#000
    },
    map {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

This is my map

```
<img src="{{ 'image.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="" usemap="#map" id="" />
<map id="map" name="map">
<area alt="" item="abc" href="#" shape="rect" coords="33,110,395,217" />
<area alt="" item="efg" href="#" shape="rect" coords="35,222,395,321" />
<div id="show_message">Click to see text.</div>
<div id="abc show_message" class="display">You clicked abc!</div>
<div id="def show_message" class="display">You clicked def!</div>

</body></html>
```

This is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[item]').click(function() {
        var item=$(this).attr('item');
        $(".display").hide();
        $("#"+item).show();
        return false;
     });
</script>
```

Comment: write hide method before click method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the text you have to do something like this

```
<div id="abc show_message" class="display">You clicked abc! <input type="button" id="hide" name="hide" value="Hide" /></div>
```

And the function hide in your js is:

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $(".display").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can create an red outline of the area clicked with the click function?

Comment: Yes, you could use  $('#ID').css("border","red solid 1px");
    $('#ID').css("border","outset"); and you could add more style like you want

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to JQuery/Java. Do I add your code within the clickFunction part? <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#1").hide(); $("#2").hide(); $("#3").hide(); $("#4").hide(); $("#5").hide(); $("#6").hide(); $("#7").hide(); 
  $("#8").hide(); $("#9").hide(); $("#10").hide(); $("#11").hide(); $("#12").hide(); $("#13").hide(); $("#14").hide();  $("#15").hide(); $("#16").hide();
 $('[item]').click(function(){
    var item=$(this).attr('item');
    $(".display").hide();
    $("#"+item).show();
    return false;
    });
 </script>

Comment: Sure! try it
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#hide').click(function(){ //the id for the element that you will click
    $(".display").hide(); // hide the element with id =display
    $('#hide').css("border","red solid 1px"); //red border
    $('#hide').css("border","outset"); //style border
});
</script>